# Create a menu using json data and onclick on menu item display dropdown in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

I have created an menu using JSON data in angular JS. Menu is created and works the way expected. Menu has 6 tabs i.e. HOME,ABOUTUS,CONTACTUS,SERVICES,LOGIN,REGISTER  on load first home page will be displayed, when about us is clicked only container data will be changed to display about us and its working fine (ngroute routing concept used) similarly other pages contactus, login, register will be routed to different pages and works fine.

Now when SERVICES tab is is clicked a dropdown should be displayed with the submenuItems "CAR TRADE","BIKE TRADE","AUTO LOAN", "INTEREST RATE".

I am facing issue in creating a submenu dropdown. I am from legacy background and learning web development and working on angular js project. Your help is appreciated.

I worked on submenu it was disaster so i have taken the useful stuff off and only working code is below:

```
           <div class="row secondarynavbar">
                <div class="col-lg-12 navigation-bar" ng-controller="menuCntrl">
                     <ul ng-repeat="menu in menulist">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#{{menu.menuUrl}}">{{menu.menuItem}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the HTML code which creates menu from JSON data.(Works fine)

Simple angular code to get json data...(works fine)

```
app.controller('menuCntrl',function($scope,$http){
$http.get('data/menujson.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.menulist = data;
}) });
```

Please help in taking it forward.

Comment: why don't you just use data-ng-repeat to create submenus?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if i use ng-repeat in <a> tag i have to create another <ul><li> and display the sub menu ??? or is there any other way??

Comment: Sorry forgot to update... I figured of the answer with submenus longback. thank you.